# Pandas Preserving data while dropping NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi all so I have the following dataframe:

```
  WM               WH          WP            LC_REF
0 Tesla        League       Test            DT 17 1C
1 Merc         Fandom       Tundra          DT 17 1C
2 Fellaine      Fark           ''           DT 17 1C
3 SeaWorld        ''           ''           DT 17 1C
4 Rectigy         ''           ''           DT 17 1C
5 Donfae          ''           ''           DT 17 1C
```

My code is this:

```
for num in range(len(df)):
    df = df.groupby('LC_REF',sort=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str).str.upper()).replace(' ','')).stack().rename_axis(('LC_REF','a')).reset_index(name='vals')
```

which produces this:

```
  LC_REF            a            vals
0 DT 17 1C         WM            Tesla,Merc,Fellaine,Seaworld,Rectigy,Donfae
1 DT 17 1C         WH            League, Fandom, Fark,,,
2 DT 17 1C         WP            Test,Tundra,,,,
```

Is there any way to remove the extra commas at the end? Somewhere in my code, as it is grouping I'd like it to drop the blank string values so it can look like this:

```
  LC_REF            a            vals
0 DT 17 1C         WM            Tesla,Merc,Fellaine,Seaworld,Rectigy,Donfae
1 DT 17 1C         WH            League, Fandom, Fark
2 DT 17 1C         WP            Test,Tundra
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.vals.apply(lambda x: x[:x.find(',,')])
```

This way you find the first occurence of ',,' and take the text up to the position of ',,'. Works even if there is only 1 comma at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, it seems to be cutting off the last letter of lines where there are no consecutive commas, so the first line becomes Tesla,Merc,Fellaine,Seaworld,Rectigy,Donfa, any tips?

Comment: Try this one: df.vals.apply(lambda x: x[:x.find(',,')] if x.endswith(',') else x)

Comment: beautiful. Thank you for your help!